# Jmeter Yaml File Value

Tags: jmeter

i have question . How to call the variable that are in yaml file in JMeter . As we are facing an issue with that . I have mention number of threads in yaml file . how to extract that value in JMeter . Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

JMeter cannot read the data from YAML files (at of [JMeter 5.5](https://lists.apache.org/thread/k575c2oqnr0pv52fckcg399o4nkqt8c6) at least)

The options are in:

1. Use [JSON/YAML Plugins](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) (can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager)

   [image]

   Check out [The New JSON/YAML Plugin: Using YAML in JMeter](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) for more details.
2. Or get a YAML parsing library like [SnakeYAML](https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml) and parse your YAML file using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) or [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)